# Mage_Core_Exception - Ebizmarts SagePaySuite - Magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, sagepay

We've been getting increasingly intermittent errors that occurs when customers try to check out using SagePay

I've looked in the exception.log and found the following.

```
2020-08-05 11:18:46.000000 (1596622726.7568) ERR: 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Your order could not be completed, please try again. Thanks.' in /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/controllers/DirectPaymentController.php(181): Mage::throwException('Your order coul...')
#1 /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_DirectPaymentController->callback3dAction()
#2 /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('callback3d')
#3 /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/x2/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/x2/public_html/shop/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

I have contacted SagePay support (opayo.co.uk) and they can't point out what the issue is.

I have also contacted the hosting support and they can't see obvious issues from their side.

Any ideas as to what might cause this?

Answer (score 2):

I am Santiago from Ebizmarts support.
This error is triggered when the cart is modified after submitting the order.
Usually other third party extensions are the cause of this problem. If you have an extension that might be causing this I recommend testing again after disabling it.

In case this does not fix the problem you can contact our support at opayo@ebizmarts-desk.zendesk.com

Regards,
Santiago.